# Late 90s - Early 2000s first-person-shot thriller

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

People who love movies always have a set of both the best and the worst movies they've ever seen. For me, I'm pretty sure this is the worst of the worst I've seen, but I really can't remember it's name, and can't find information about it. I hope you can help me out, because knowing which is your top-worst is valuable information ;)

What I remember is this:

- The movie was shot in first-person.
- The main character had some sort of mental disorder, and was taking treatment for it at a clinic.
- Every morning the main character writes down the current hour she wakes up.
- The main character falls in love with the receptionist of the clinic and kidnaps her.
- The police/detective who takes the case befriends or falls in love too with the recepcionist girl (can't remember if they knew each other before the kidnapping).
- When the girl is rescued the main character manages to escape.
- After the girl is rescued, the main character attacks her in the hospital where she's recovering for her wounds. The police/detective manages to rescue her again and shots and hurts the main character, but she manages to escape again.
- The "big shocking" plot twist at the end of the movie is that the main character is a woman (there's no clue about her gender in the rest of the movie).

I'm pretty sure it was an american movie. I watched it around 2002 ~ 2003, and it still was in VHS format. The title in spanish is something like "Alucinaciones" (hallucinations) but I think the original title in english had little to do with this word.

I hope this is enough information; ask if you want to know more about it but this is pretty much all I can remember.

Comment: Great question, but unfortunately all I can think of is that notorious Prodigy music video.

Answer (score 6):

I'm almost certain you're looking for [Alone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0263053/) (2002)

[image]

You've described the movie well, and I remember all the details you've provided.

It's shot in first person, much of it narrated by the killer, and it's a pretty awful movie and I would have happily forgotten all about it, if it hadn't been for an extremely disturbing murderscene that involves force feeding.

**The killer is indeed a woman who is seeing a therapist** and most importantly **she carefully notes the time she wakes every morning.**

Here's a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG6LUWi7dXg).

Comment: Seems like it. I think I can recall some scenes that appear in the trailer. I'll look for it and accept the answer once confirmed. Thanks!